# please help me PHP and SQL

Tags: php, sql

I am working on school project. Student Attendance System.
there are three panels
1. Admin

```
        1.1. Add/Update Admin (Done).
        1.2. Add/Update Teacher (Done).
        1.3. Assign Subject to teacher (Not Done). (Need Help There)
        1.4. Add/Update Subject to Student (Done)
        1.5. Assign Subject to Student (Not Done) (Need Help There)
        1.6. Add/Update Subject (Done)
```

2. Teacher

```
         2.1. Click subject And Get List of Student who choose his subject  (Need Help There)
         2.2. Mark Attendance and Select Date (i will do that)
```

3. Student

   ```
        3.1. Enter Roll no to get Attendance detail (i will do that).
   ```

problem one 1.3:how to assign subject to a teacher. i mean subject and teacher are two diff. tables. how can i use both information and save them to 3rd table.

problem two 1.5 :same as 1,3

problem three 2.1: how to fatch student name when teacher select a subject.

just give me hint i will do that on my own. no need to write coding just a syntax.
thanks in advance

Comment: you're asking for pseudocode?

Comment: That's pretty basic SQL. I guess your teacher told you about JOINS and FOREIGN KEYS at some point.

Comment: Reference the different tables to each other somehow. IE: in the subjects table, have a column named owner_id. Use that column to refer to a teachers row ID. And then use JOIN on you query

Comment: yeah just like that @Huey.

Comment: please read last line 
**just give me hint i will do that on my own. no need to write coding just a syntax. thanks in advance**

Comment: @JasjeetSingh I think that you would have gotten less down votes if you had identified the problem better and removed the irrelevant parts. The real problem is something like "I have a table of Teachers and a table of Subjects in SQL. How can I let each Teacher have a list of subjects assigned to them?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a new table that acts as a link between the `subject` and `teacher`, lets call it `teacher_subject`. The table should have three columns: `id`, `subjectId` and `teacherId`.

To add a subject to the teacher, just insert a new row with the correct `subjectId` and `teacherId`.

To get all the subjects that a teacher has, something like this should work:

```
SELECT subject.*
FROM subject, teacher_subject
WHERE subject.id = teacher_subject.subjectId
AND teacher_subject.teacherId = ?
```